# How to use elements (labels, images) in a static method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some elements in my project

```
<Label x:Name="winsLabel"  Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Margin="68,429.065,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
<Label x:Name="lossesLabel" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Margin="180,429.065,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
```

And I'm trying to set values to these labels in a static method:

```
public static void ResetGame()
{
    score_wins = 0;
    score_losses = 0;
    score_draws = 0;

    winsLabel.Content = score_wins;
    lossesLabel.Content = score_losses;
}
```

But this error (Error 14 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'mainRockPaperTest.MainWindow.winsLabel') confuses me.

Can I make static labels or images in XAML? Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't.  Why is it static?  Seems perfectly reasonable for it to be an instance method. (especially it if uses instance properties).

Comment: static because i want to call this method from other class without  instance...or it's wrong? It's a MainWindow class but why create a second instance for MainWindow?

Comment: Without an instance there is no Label that you can set.

Comment: It's wrong.  You need a reference to the form to access the controls.

Comment: Okey! But then how to get access to this method in MainWindow from UserControl?

Comment: Provide a property for your UserControl that lets you set the MainWindow object.

Comment: If you need static methods in order to operate on an object from anywhere, you need a static reference to it.  Sounds like you want a Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class and derive your views from it, define those elements into the class, and then you can pass a reference to `ResetGame`:

```
public static void ResetGame(BaseClass baseClass)
{
    score_wins = 0;
    score_losses = 0;
    score_draws = 0;

    baseClass.winsLabel.Content = score_wins;
    baseClass.lossesLabel.Content = score_losses;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you really should look into data binding. Reaching into the form to set values is not good XAML-fu.